# WordPress Permalinks Issue

Tags: ubuntu, wordpress

I seem to be having an issue with my wordpress blog

I am running it on Ubuntu and the Permalinks are not working.

It says "Not Found Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here."

It looks like this is somewhat of a know issue but there is no clear fix.

Take a look here:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/302626

Please help.

Comment: There is a WordPress StackExchange site winding it's way through the process at Area51. I invite any WordPress users/admins here to check it out and "commit" if you think it would be helpful. I did! http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500/wordpress-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like it could be something to do with mod_rewrite on Apache - this needs to enabled if you change the permalink structure from the default in the wordpress settings.

The default is usually something like: ?p=9

In settings you can change it to something like: /2009/11/16/post-title/

The second version needs mod_rewrite enabled